# How do I write my xml output to a file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I currently have a Python script that does a get request and prints out the data which is in xml format. How do I dump this output to a xml file for parsing?

Comment: if you use https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a string variable containing the xml data, you can do the following:

```
with open("output.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

Answer (score 5):

if you use [Elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

ET.SubElement(doc, "field1", name="blah").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "field2", name="asdfasd").text = "some vlaue2"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```